# Регулярное выражение для поиска ссылки в RSS

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, rss, simplexml

Помогите пожалуйста исправить ошибку в данном регулярном выражении:`/^src=/([^']+/i/'z)`

К примеру ссылку надо извлекать из следующей строки:

```
<img title='A.B. said his only regret was having to wage a court battle in his final months.' height='259' alt='assisted suicide' width='460' src='http://i.cbc.ca/1.2950084.1458319055!/fileImage/httpImage/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/16x9_460/assisted-suicide.jpg' /> <p>While more than 118 people have received a doctor-assisted death since the procedure became legal in Canada, that number likely represents only one tenth of those who made "serious requests" for medical help in dying, a Toronto physician says.</p>
```

Картинка может быть и типа .png.
Пример исходного кода:

```
for (Item item : mRss.getChannel().getItem()) {

        String link = item.getDescription();

        String PATTERN = "/^src=/([^']+/i/'z)";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(PATTERN);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(link);

        link = link.substring(m.start(), m.end());
        item.setLinkToImage(link);
```

Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".+src='(.+)'");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
if (matcher.find())
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```